# Cocos2d PushScene and CCFadeTransition does work correctly together without scheduler?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

is there a reason why when you use CCTransitionFade this way.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 [director_ pushScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1 
 scene:[FirstScene node]]];

 return YES;

}
```

and then the Second Scene is called inside the FirstScene's init to advance like a regular brand presentation of the game, why is it that if I don't put a scheduler that is a bit longer than the first CCTransitionFade timer why does it get stuck?

```
//in FirstScene Class
-(void) onEnter {

self = [super init];
if (self) {

   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:
   [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.2 scene:[SecondScene node]]];
  }
 return self;
}
```

I mean I understand the reason why, but does this mean I have been doing this the wrong way? Is there a more acceptable way to do this CCTransitionFades or is it correct to use the Scheduler this way?

```
//in FirstScene Class
```

-(void) onEnter {

```
self = [super init];
if (self) {

  [self scheduleOnce:@selector(makeTransition:) delay:1.2];

 }
 return self;
}


-(void)makeTransition:(ccTime)dt {


      [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:
      [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[SecondScene node]]];

}
```

By doing it the second way with SchedulerOnce I am able to sucessfully get what I want.

so, am I doing something wrong? Is this just a bad workaround from my side? Or is there a correct way to this situation?

Note: Made a correction because Currently I do have the code with onEnter method. but I have tried it with init and it does have the same behavior as well.

Answer (score 0):

In first case when you call replaceScene from init, the order of calling functions looks something like that:

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
- [FirstScene node]
- FirstSceneInit
- [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: ..
- ...
- [director_ pushScene

  The problem is because you call replaceScene when there aren't scene on screen, so the director try change the actual scene, which is NULL to FirstScene. The first scene appear on the screen after pushScene

In the second mostly works, but theoretically this solution is dangerous, because when you call init and set scheduler, then can be 2 seconds lag for example. I don't know that this is possible on cocos2d, which operate in one thread, but i think that putting replace scene in onEnter function is more elegant solution

Comment: Look at the update... I have tried both scenarios, onEnter and init and they both behave the same way. Your concept of getting locked might be correct but has never happened to me unless I intentionally put less time than the previous scene transition timer on the scheduler timer.

Comment: Maybe in onEnterTransitionDidFinish() it will works.